# Groupby top n records based on another column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Below is an example of the data set I am working with. I am trying to do a group by on Location for only the top 3 locations based on KGs.

```
Location KG Dollars
BKK     7   2
BKK     5   3
BKK     4   2
BKK     3   3
BKK     2   2
HKG     8   3
HKG     6   2
HKG     4   3
HKG     3   2
HKG     2   3
```

The output would look like below. Grouped on the location, summing both KG and Dollars for the top 3 KG records for each location.

```
Location KG Dollars
BKK     16  7
HKG     18  8
```

I've tried different types of groupbys, just having a problem only specifying the top n KG records for the groupby.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do

```
In [610]: df.groupby('Location').apply(lambda x: 
               x.nlargest(3, 'KG')[['KG', 'Dollars']].sum())
Out[610]:
          KG  Dollars
Location
BKK       16        7
HKG       18        8
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for, thank you for the help!